# calculating the determinant of a matrix with cupy (python)

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, cupy

Im currently editing code for use with Cupy in python for GPU acceleration. Most of the edits have required a straight swap from numpy to cupy (e.g cp.array instead of np.array) with a few minor exceptions. However, Im having trouble with this section of code, it works with numpy and im unsure of why I suddenly get this error. I have the following code

```
ab = (b - a)
ac = (c - a)
ap1 = (p1 - a)
ap2 = (p2 - a)
```

where a,b,c,p1 and p2 are all 1D Cupy arrays

From here I want to use the following to calculate the determinants.

```
testP1 = 1 if cp.linalg.det([ab,ac,ap1]) >0 else 0
testP2 = 1 if cp.linalg.det([ab,ac,ap2]) >0 else 0
```

This works fine in numpy (with the inputs being numpy rather than cupy arrays), however, I now get the following error

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Comment: Don't use a list as an input to `det`. Use a or numpy or cupy array

Comment: Did you try to explicitely convert `[ab,ac,ap1]` to a `cp.array` object? Maybe numpy does the conversion implicitely while cupy doesn't.

Comment: Hi @g2i thats what it was, I stupidly tried every other combination including transferring between array types before I tried the simplest option. Thank you

Comment: Hi MattC1990, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

As g2i commented, cupy doesnt implicitly convert to an array whilst numpy does, hence the conversion to a cupy array must be done explicitly